# Not allowing deletion of records by any user except through stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am working on a project and in one of my tables I want users (any user) not to be able to delete rows, unless deletion is done through a stored procedure.

There is a question about this and has an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/366931/4810628

But I need to know how to enforce such policy in SQL Server.

Thanks

Comment: Triggers? Permissions? Are users able to run SQL commands directly anyway? If you're trying to stop a sa doing it, I don't think there's really a way.

Comment: remove (DENY) everyone's permissions to do deletes to the table, add (GRANT) them permissions to execute the stored proc

Comment: @CharlesBretana where I can do such settings?

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1138/giving-and-removing-permissions-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove ([DENY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173724.aspx)) everyone's permissions to do deletes to the table, add ([GRANT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345484.aspx)) them permissions to execute the stored proc.

Comment: instead of specific user in "TO Recruiting11; " what should I use if I want to it for everyone?

Comment: You can use Roles.

Comment: Yes if you're allowing actual users to connect directly to database, just assign them to a role and then assign (Grant/Deny) permissions to the role, not to the individual users. But better is to have middle tier use an application account to connect to the database and have all users go through middle tier.